# Which IDE should I use to write Pythonic-programs for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, python

I'm doing my first baby-steps to build tools using Arduino. I'd like to know if there is a way to write python scripts to build programs for Arduino. Most of IDEs I found are non-supported IDEs. Is there any "recommended" IDEs that I should use.

Comment: Before asking about an IDE you should ask if it's even possible in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended IDE for writing **C/C++** for Arduino for beginners is the formal Arduino IDE, of which you can read more on the [arduino.cc website](http://arduino.cc/en/main/software).

**Python** is an interpreter language, and as such, require an interpreter running on the target machine. Unfortunately, the Arduino does not natively support running an Python interpreter, although some efforts has been made in that direction, for example the [Python on a chip project](https://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/), or the [Python Arduino Proto API v2](https://github.com/vascop/Python-Arduino-Proto-API-v2). 
See [this SO question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/105/programming-an-arduino-using-python-rather-than-c-c) for more details. If you go with any of these options, the IDE you would use would be your favorite Python IDE.

Note that both projects have their downsides, and actually there is no real alternative equivalent to running compiled C/C++ code on the Arduino. If you have strong Python programming abilities, this shouldn't be too hard for you as well :)